# Hide core logic and show only wrapper APIs to application

Tags: java, eclipse

I have 2 Java projects. One project (say A) has core functions and another project (say B) is wrapper over project A. I have included jar of project A in project B. If someone now uses project B jar then I want to expose APIs of project B only. Currently it is exposing APIs of both projects A and B.

Comment: What build system are you using? Usually, you would only give B as a compile-time dependency to the user, and only use A as a run-time dependency (i.e. only put B on compiler classpath, and both A and B on runtime classpath).

Comment: These are two Maven projects. I have added dependency of project A into project B in pom.xml. Now I am creating jar of project B but it shows both project functions to user.